# Error in conversion to swift 3 syntax for an existing cocoapods integrated project

Tags: xcode, swift3

I've recently upgraded to xcode 8 and did a conversion for my xcode project. While every other swift files checks out fine, there seems to be issues with this particular swift file.

[image]

I suspect it could be a result of cocoapods not being updated and thus I did a repo update to the latest pre version before doing a pod install on the project again but still to no avail.

Comment: `@testable import` needs to be followed by the name of the module that you are importing for testing. Did you name your module `_`?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ok I found a way to fix this, apparently just going to product>clean will solve most of the problems. This is for anyone out there converting to swift 3. Now on to solve some other problems...